# 'Unable to invoke CFC - The data for must be no more than 100 characters in length

Tags: actionscript-3, coldfusion, maxlength

I'm trying to call a method as follows:

```
<cfinvoke component="#variables.target#"
      method="#arguments.methodName#"
      argumentcollection="#arguments.args#"
      returnvariable="rtn">
</cfinvoke>
```

However, I am getting the following error:

> Unable to invoke CFC - The data for 'param_value' must be no more than
>   100 characters in length.' faultDetail:''

The variable `arguments.args` is a struct and one of its elements looks like this:

```
{
    param_name: 'property_uid',
    param_value : '00000000-0000-0000-0000-0000000213131200,00002131300-0000-0000-0000-000000000000,00000000-0000-0000-0000-0000000002122,00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000032242
}
```

I know the problem is caused by this element, but don't know how to fix it.
Note that I've already updated the Maximum number of POST request parameters from 100 to 300 in the CF Administrator.

Comment: Invoking a dynamically determined method of a dynamically determined component with a dynamic argument list is a code smell for me. What are you building? A dynamic method invocator function? Could it be you are overengineering?

Comment: What part of your question has to do with [tag:actionscript-3]?

Comment: The fact is I'm trying to send parameters from ActionScript. I found the solution anyway. Sent multiple parameters rather than one with a huge coma separated string...

Answer (score 0):

The variable `property_uid` is currently a list and the list's value is too long to be passed in as a struct key's value. Use `listToArray()` to send the data as an array. Inside the function, convert it back using `arrayToList()` if you need the data as a list again.

Comment: But why do we have a limit on the list items? is there any reference for the limits on the arguments we can pass to a component? a reference would help.

Comment: Why would the string length of an argument value matter at all? In fact it doesn't, I justed tested the code in the question.

Comment: In fact I pass to param_value a string , not a list or Array. I think should be some restrictions added somewhere..

Answer (score 0):

Please check the code of the invoked function (the function name can be found in your variable `arguments.methodName` in the component of `variables.target`).

Look for the tag `<cfparam name="param_value" ...>` and check if there is a `maxlength` attribute defined. It's probably set to `100` and thus causes ColdFusion to throw an exception if you pass more than 100 characters to said parameter.

Having a limit of 100 characters is probably a design descision on your side (database scheme?), so you need to figure this out by yourself.